# Spring: Injecting Inner bean info

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can I realize this:

```
 @Autowired
 private ArticoliOrdine articoliOrdine;

 @Autowired
 private Ordine ordine;

  //I want to do this in my applicationContext
 ArticlesOrderPK pk=new ArticolesOrderPK(order.getId(),article.getId());
```

The two getId()methods return either an Integer

In my applicationContext I tried to do this:

```
<bean class="bean.ArticlesOrder" id="ArticlesOrder">
    <property name="ArticlesOrderPK">
        <bean class="bean.ArticolesOrderPK" id="ArticolesOrderPK">
            <property name="idOrder" ref=""/>
            <property name="idArticle" ref="" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="bean.Ordine" id="order" scope="prototype"/>
```

How can I bind ArticlesOrderPK.idOrder to Order.id and ArticolesOrderPK.idArticle to Article.id?
Thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *`SpEL - Spring Expression Language`* which comes with **Spring 3.x** + 
In the value attribute of bean definition (which you need to bind with other beans' property) use an expression as below

```
#{beanId.beanProperty} or #{beanId.someMethod()}
```

In your case it should be something like below

```
<bean class="bean.ArticolesOrderPK" id="ArticolesOrderPK">
        <property name="idOrder" value="#{order.getId()}"/>
        <property name="idArticle" value="#{article.getId()}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: @alex do share your findings / results